# Отправить через телеграм бота видео 1.4 ГБ

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть код

```
def send(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    v = Video(FILES_TO_COPY)
    videos = sorted(v.all_videos, key=lambda x: v.get_id(x))
    with open(FILES_TO_COPY+videos[0], mode='rb') as f:
            context.bot.send_video(update.message.chat_id, f, caption=videos[0])
```

После его запуска видео начинает отправляться, но потом, секунд через 10-12 происходит разрыв

```
telegram.error.NetworkError: urllib3 HTTPError The operation did not complete (write) (_ssl.c:2423)
```

Еще пробовал с другой библиотекой

```
def start_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello!")
    with open("file_name.mp4", mode='rb') as f:
        bot.send_video(message.chat.id, f, caption=r"file_name.mp4")
```

Код ошибки другой, но также обрывает

Если же посылаю маленькие видео, то они иногда отсылаются 50/50

Как исправить?

Comment: пробовали ? https://habr.com/ru/post/348234/

Comment: @Интик, по идее хороший вариант, но он вроде как предназначен для музыки, если я правильно понял, да и не до конца понятна суть работы. Что за аргумент `chat_id`, это id бота, который должен отправить видео? Как получить `object_id`?

Comment: `chat_id` — для кого предназначается данный файл, `object_id` в базе данных, к которому нужно привязать `file_id`. всё же написано. и суть работы в том, что **от имени пользователя загружается файл** на сервера Telegram, а **бот отправляет файл с помощью** `file_id`. и для получения "кредов" на пользователя - https://my.telegram.org/auth